# Python module that can open AND close an image

Tags: python, module

I've tried out PIL, Matplotlib, and pygame, they all can open an image in a new window easy, but it either can't be closed via command, or - in pygame's case - cannot reopen with a new image. Are there any module(s) that can do this?

Here's an example of the code it goes through:

```
#this just waits for input from the user to continue
def pause():
  ps = input("\n[Press 'Enter' to continue]\n")


image = eval(unit).image
#yes, I know eval is bad but shhhhh, it works

#the main function
def function(foo):
  #Code displays information, nothing that should cause problems
  something.display(image.png)
  #line or several lines of code to hide image()
  page(pg)
```

Is anything like this possible?
the only requirement is that whatever window it opens to display the window can be closed, and reopened with a different image

Comment: most GUIs need even loop which checks key/mouse/other events and it can close window.

Comment: matplotlib `plt.show(block=False)` and it doesn't block code so you can do other calculations and later close plot using `plt.close()`

Comment: as I know `matploblib` and `PIL` has `show()` rather for debugging purpose - but all people use it all the time. If you need something more then you should rather use GUI frameworks like Tkitner, PyQt, wxPython, PyGTK to create window with event loop and then you can control it.

Comment: if you get error when you use PyGame then add full error message in question (not in comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have problem to reopen window in `PyGame` with new image on Linux but maybe it depends on system. (BTW: Some systems may need to get events to show window)

```
import pygame
import time

#pygame.init()

def imshow(filename):
    #pygame.init()
    img = pygame.image.load(filename)
    size = img.get_rect().size
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    #pygame.event.clear()

def imclose():
    #pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.quit()

imshow('image1.jpg')
time.sleep(3)
imclose()

imshow('image2.png')
time.sleep(3)
imclose()
```

---

**EDIT:** I have no problem to do the same in `matplotlib`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread('image1.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.pause(3)
plt.close()

img = plt.imread('image2.png')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.pause(3)
plt.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** Pygame version which closes window on pressing key `Enter/Return` (or using button `[X]`).

But it blocks other code and it has to wait till you close window.

```
import pygame

#pygame.init()

def imshow(filename):
    #pygame.init()
    img = pygame.image.load(filename)
    size = img.get_rect().size
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # close by button [X]
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    running = False
    pygame.display.quit()
    #pygame.quit()


imshow('image1.jpg')
imshow('image2.png')
```

---

To show window which can be closed by `Enter` and run other commands at the same time it would have to run `PyGame` in thread.

This code runs `PyGame` in thread and you can close it with `Enter/Return`. If you don't close it then code will close it using `imclose()` after few other commands (emulated by `sleep()`)

```
import pygame

import threading
import time

def window(filename):
    global running 

    running = True

    #pygame.init()
    img = pygame.image.load(filename)
    size = img.get_rect().size
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # close by button [X]
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: # close by ENTER
                    running = False

    pygame.display.quit()
    #pygame.quit()

def imshow(filename):
    threading.Thread(target=window, args=(filename,)).start()

def imclose():
    global running
    running = False

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

imshow('image1.jpg')
# emulate other commands
for x in range(3):
    print('1. other command ...', x)
    time.sleep(1)
imclose() # close by command

# emulate other commands
for x in range(3):
    print('2. other command ...', x)
    time.sleep(1)

imshow('image2.jpg')
# emulate other commands
for x in range(3):
    print('3. other command ...', x)
    time.sleep(1) # emulate other code
imclose() # close by command
```

Similar code with `Tkinter`

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import threading
import time

def window(filename):
    global running

    running = True

    def on_press(event):
        global running
        running = False

    root = tk.Tk()    
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
    label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
    label.photo = photo
    label.pack()
    root.bind('<Return>', on_press) # close by ENTER
    #root.mainloop()

    while running:
        root.update()

    root.destroy()

def imshow(filename):
    threading.Thread(target=window, args=(filename,)).start()

def imclose():
    global running
    running = False

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

imshow('image1.jpg')
# emulate other commands
for x in range(3):
    print('1. other command ...', x)
    time.sleep(1)
imclose() # close by command

# emulate other commands
for x in range(3):
    print('2. other command ...', x)
    time.sleep(1)

imshow('image2.jpg')
# emulate other commands
for x in range(3):
    print('3. other command ...', x)
    time.sleep(1) # emulate other code
imclose() # close by command
```

Comment: This fixes the reopening problem, but is there a way to keep the image open until the user hits enter rather than put it on a timer?

Comment: well, you didn't say you want to close by key but by command - and command `close()` does it. For Pygame you would have to create loop which check event and exit loop when you get event pygame.KEYDOWN  with key `Enter`.

Comment: if you want both methods at the same time - close by Enter and close by command - then it can make problem because event loop blocks other code and it would have to run in separated thread.

Comment: I added examples which use `threading` to run window with `PyGame` and `Tkinter`. Both can be closed using key `Enter` or using command `imclose()`