# Python non blocking notification / message

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have very basic simple requirements, I have to display non-blocking message information on Windows 10 while my running python program (3.X) everytime I run a program, but it requires 2 main conditions

1. It should be non-blocking, it means my python program does not wait for user action to close or any other action from user
2. Secondly, message should not disappear when program get executed.

I tried tkinter, win10Toas,Plyer ...etc. but not successful to achieve this simple result.

my code in tkinter as follows

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_message(type1, msg1, msg2, msg3):
    root = tk.Tk()
    if type1 == "L":
        h1 = "LOSS Notifications"
        tk.Label(root, text=msg1, fg="red", bg="yellow", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
        tk.Label(root, text=msg2, fg="red", bg="yellow", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
        tk.Label(root, text=msg3, fg="black", bg="orange", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
    elif type1 == "P":
        h1 = "Profit Notifications"
        tk.Label(root, text=msg1, fg="yellow", bg="blue", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
        tk.Label(root, text=msg2, fg="yellow", bg="blue", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
        tk.Label(root, text=msg3, fg="white", bg="green", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
    elif type1 == "N":
        h1 = "No Loss No Profit Notifications"
        tk.Label(root, text=msg1, fg="black", bg="white", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
        tk.Label(root, text=msg2, fg="black", bg="white", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
        tk.Label(root, text=msg3, fg="black", bg="white", font="Verdana 14 bold").pack()
    root.title(h1)
    root.bell()
    tk.mainloop()
```

this code is waiting for user action, without this program is not getting successfully completed

Can you pl help ?

Comment: in win10Toast notification disappears as soon as program is finished, i do not want notification to disappear

Comment: run it in `thread` and then `mailoop` will not block main thread with rest of your code. All GUIs need loop which works all time to get key/mouse events from system and update window.

Comment: eventually try `tk.update()` instead of `tk.mainloop()` and it will (re)draw window only once and you will need to use again `tk.update()` when you change something in window.

Comment: @furas can you show an example ?

Comment: first try `tk.update()` instead of `tk.mainloop()` - it doesn't need example.

Comment: or rather `root.update()` instead of `tk.mainloop()`

Comment: in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58295797/1832058) I shows how to use `thread` to create non-blocking window with image. Last code use `tkinter` for this. Window can be still close using `Enter` or using command `close()`

Comment: @furas I done changes root.update() and it works fine. My program is having a loop and displays the notifications without blocking. But when my program is complete it removes all notifications. I do not want notifications to disappear

Comment: then don't stop program. it can't stay on screen if program doesn't run.

Comment: or you would have to run (all time) separated program which will only display window with messages. And main program would have to somehow send text to this program - ie. using file, socket, database, or message queue. it would be similar to system's notifiactions (which you can also use to display messages) but  they stay on screen only short time.

Comment: @furas OK thanks understood, now my tikinter windows messages are overlapping on each other can I avoid this ?

Comment: using `root.geometry('+1000+200')` you can set window in position `100,200` so you can put windows in different positions but you have to do it manually. If you want to close previous window then you would have to keep `root` in global variable and use `root.destroy()`. If you want to append labels to existing window then you would have to also keep `root` in global variable and then add new Labels to existing window.